Implement ZeroTier In Android Studio
Can someone help me on my way to implement zerotier to make users connect to an network?
Trying on windows but i don't install libzt, i have virtual machine linux.
Trying to connect multiple users to a same network, it is goin to be a simple app that shares connection.
